# Use namespace alias in twig

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, twig

I have a code that checks some entity constant in a twig template:

```
{% if logRecord.status is constant('App\\DealBundle\\Entity\\Deal::DEAL_STATE_MONEY_RESERVED') %}
```

But it is so embarrassing to use such a long class name everytime. Is there any way to make a namespace alias in twig? Something like:

```
{% use App\\DealBundle\\Entity\\Deal %}
{% if logRecord.status is constant('Deal::DEAL_STATE_MONEY_RESERVED') %}
```

Or I always need to write full class names?

Comment: You always need to write the full class name. Ever thought about [creating a twig test](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id5) so you can do it like `if logRecord.status is state('reserved')`?

Comment: yep you could write an twig function for that.

Comment: @Maerlyn yes, I will probably make a custom test for it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem and the solution turned out to be very simple. This macro won't work in our case because we want to use the constant value not only for rendering but also as a value (int, string, float etc.). This is impossible because with this macro Twig converts the value into a Twig_Markup class.

So the solution is the next one. Somewhere in the template you declare:

```
    {% set namespace = 'App\\DealBundle\\Entity\\' %}
```

Then in another place you can use it like this:

```
    {% if logRecord.status is constant(namespace~'Deal::DEAL_STATE_MONEY_RESERVED') %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) :

```
{% macro state(name) -%}
   {{ constant('App\\DealBundle\\Entity\\Deal::DEAL_STATE_' ~ name) }}
{%- endmacro %}
```

And use it this way :

```
{% if logRecord.status == _self.state('MONEY_RESERVED') %}
```

Don't forget to use hyphens ( - ) to remove whitespaces in your macro.

Comment: Oh no, it doesn't work: `Object of class Twig_Markup could not be converted to int`. So it returns a macro object, not it's value.

Comment: I tested it and it works :-) But you just forgot to do what I warned: put hyphens in your `{%` and `%}` (look at my example). Or do `{% macro state(name) %}{{ constant('App\\DealBundle\\Entity\\Deal::DEAL_STATE_' ~ name) }}{% endmacro %}` in a single line to avoid that whitespace matter.

Comment: No, I didn't forget. I even tested it in one line like you said. But there is still the same error :(

Comment: Can you copy/paste it here? And what is your Symfony2 version?

Comment: Symfony 2.1. Maybe this is the case? Marco and it's usage looks exactly like yours letter by letter.

Answer (score 0):

I am updating this just in case someone has the same issue than me and don't want to use any special extension.

@alain-tiemblo's answer is right, it is like twig doesn't recognize `_self` object anymore. So the only thing to do is to import it, as in:

```
{% macro state(name) -%}
    {{ constant('App\\DealBundle\\Entity\\Deal::DEAL_STATE_' ~ name) }}
{%- endmacro %}
{# ### Remember the import! ### #}
{% import _self as localMacros %}
```

And  after that you can use

```
{% if logRecord.status == localMacros.state('MONEY_RESERVED') %}
```